# How to return the root of a trie that is added to recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, trie

I am trying to use a linked list to add a string to a trie with '$' as the terminating character. However, it only returns the last node of the Trie and not the root of the trie. This is my code:

```
public class DictionaryDLB{

    private Node root;

    private class Node{
        public char value;
        public Node next;
        public Node child;

        public Node() {}
        public Node(char value){
            this.value = value;
            this.next = null;
            this.child = null;
        }
    }
    public void add(String word){
        root = add(root, word, 0);
    }

    private Node add(Node root, String key, int d){
        char c;
        if (d != key.length()) c = key.charAt(d);
        else c = '$';
        if (root == null) root = new Node(c);
        if (d == key.length()) { return root; }
        if (c != root.value) root = add(root.next, key, d);
        return root = add(root.child, key, d+1);
    }
```

upon completion it returns the node with the value of `$` and has no child or next nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you're setting `root` to the return value of `add` before you return `root`. The result is that you will get the last instance of `root` from the call stack. For example, let's say I called `add("hi")`. Here's how the function call stack would look like assuming root starts off as `null`,

```
add("hi")
root = add(root, "hi", 0)
    root = new Node('h')
    return root = add(root.child, "hi", 1)
        root = new Node('i')
        return root = add(root.child, "hi", 2)
            root = new Node('$')
            return root //Node('$')
        return root //Node('$')
    return root //Node('$')
root = root //Node('$')
```

Notice what's being passed down the function calls is the node with a value of `'$'`. The reason is that you're setting `root` to the return value of `add` at the bottom of your method. There's no need to do this. Just call `add` like you are doing currently and return `root` separately like so,

```
private Node add(Node root, String key, int d){
    char c;
    if (d != key.length()) c = key.charAt(d);
    else c = '$';
    if (root == null) root = new Node(c);
    if (d == key.length()) { return root; }
    if (c != root.value) root.next = add(root.next, key, d);
    else root.child = add(root.child, key, d+1);
    return root;
}
```

You now have to set the result of `add` to either root.next or root.child. The reason for this is that the node created in the call to `add` has to be passed back to set either the next or child pointers. To better illustrate, let's rerun an example stack trace for `add("hi")`.

```
add("hi")
root = add(root, "hi", 0)
    root = new Node('h')
    root.child = add(root.child, "hi", 1)
        root = new Node('i')
        root.child = add(root.child, "hi", 2)
            root = new Node('$')
            return root //Node('$')
        root.child = root //Node('$')
        return root //Node('i')
    root.child = root //Node('i')
    return root //Node('h')
root = root //Node('h')
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! But unfortunately it still only returns the node that contains 't' and none of the linked nodes. I can only assume that it must be something that is wrong with the method itself, I guess. Any ideas what part is causing it to return the node with the siblings and children unlinked?

Comment: @IanLundberg what is the string you're inputting when it returns a node containing 't'?

Comment: oh I apologize. "test" Sorry for assuming your omniscience haha

Comment: @IanLundberg isn't that the expected result? assuming the 't' is associated with the first 't' in "test".

Comment: Yeah! But the node doesn't contain a link to the child node: e. Which would then contain a link to child node: s, etc. Here is a screencap of the debugger: https://i.gyazo.com/809bf15099d27660dbfd6615cc44be4c.png

Comment: @IanLundberg oh I understand the issue, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Awesome! I had to also add an else for `root.child = add(root.child, key, d+1);` Otherwise it would add subsequent add(word);s to the root twice, but you were a huge help so thanks!

Comment: @IanLundberg No problem, if you found the answer helpful please consider accepting or upvoting the answer.

Comment: Haha I did, was just waiting to see if you'd add the else part and you did! Thanks again.